# Geodesic-unclear operator $\nabla$

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, manifolds, connections

I understand what is a connection $$\nabla_X\textbf{v}$$ for a vector $X$ and a vector field $\textbf{v}$ near point $p$.

However I do not understand $(10.5)$ below, namely what is $$\frac{\nabla}{dt}$$

**The snippet:**

[image]

Comment: Probably the connection $\nabla_X$ with $X$ the tangent vector to the curve at time $t$ would be my guess, but it's been a little while, so I might be misremembering how this all works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stands for the Levi-Civita connection along the curve $\mathbf{x}(t)$. By definition it is
$$
 \frac{\nabla}{dt}\left(\frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt}\right) = \nabla_{\frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt}} X
$$
where $X$ is a local vector field on $M$ such that $X(\mathbf{x}(t)) = \frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt}(t)$. 
This definition makes sense because the value $\nabla_X Y(p)$ only depend on the vector $v=X(p)$ at the point $p$ and the values of $Y$ along a curve $\alpha:I\to M$ with $\alpha(0)=p$ and $\alpha'(0) = v$.

Intuitively one can course just think of this as "the Levi-Civita connection restricted to the curve". However, there are some technicalities involved, and in order to emphasize these, some references use a separate notation, such as  $\nabla/{dt}$ or $D/dt$. Other sources use the more loose notation $\nabla_{d\mathbf{x}/dt}$.

Comment: This is too restrictive. If $\mathbf x(t)$ is a curve in our manifold, then $$\frac{\nabla}{dt} Y = \nabla_{d\mathbf x/dt} Y$$ for any vector field defined along (or in a neighborhood) of our curve. (Oh, I see, you were talking specifically about stuff in the original citation. I ignored that. :P)

Comment: @TedShifrin Does it make any difference whether the $Y$ is along *or* in the neighborhood ?

Comment: You actually only need $Y$ defined along the curve in order to define this. If $Y$ and $Y'$ agree along the curve, then $\nabla/dt (Y-Y') = 0$, as you can check, e.g., in coordinates.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm a beginner to coordinates (and to differential geometry in general). Could you please explain to me how to do this: $\nabla/dt(Y-Y')=0$

Comment: If $Y=\sum a^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ and $\nabla_{\partial/\partial x^j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} = \sum\Gamma^k_{ij}  \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$, then $$\frac{\nabla}{dt} Y = \sum \frac{da^i}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} + a^i \nabla_{d{\mathbf x}/dt} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} = \sum \frac{da^i}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} + a^i \frac{d\mathbf x^j}{dt} \Gamma^k_{ij} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}.$$ If $a^i=0$ along the curve, then you clearly get $0$. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin OK. And how $Y '$ comes into the play ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, write it for $Y-Y'$. The point is that if the coefficients of a vector field vanish along the curve $\mathbf x(t)$, then the covariant derivative of the vector field is $0$ along the curve.